# Debug Windows Mobile in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, windows-mobile

is there any way to debug a J2ME application in a Windows Mobile emulator in Netbeans?

Just can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Look into adding J2ME support to netbeans : http://netbeans.org/community/releases/36/J2ME_Support.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a real debugging session there (like using breakpoints). A workaround is installing one java runtime for windows mobile (something like Esmertec Jbed) and writing something in console with System.out.println(), windows mobile emulator will echo your debugging texts. also you can use alerts for debugging.
A very good alternative is creating a debugging class: Place two MIDlets on your j2me project. one of them for your real MIDlet, and another for reading debug lines from an RMS. in running mode, you can write your debugging line in the RMS, and after a run, you can read them in the another MIDlet. you will find this approach so clean. You can also integrate this debugging idea with netbeans or j2me polish's pre-processing feature.